# Rationale for Continuity of Azimuthal Equation

Tags: wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions, differential-equations

To solve Laplace's equation $\nabla^2\psi =0$ or the Schrödinger equation: $$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2\psi+V\psi =E\psi$$ in spherical coordinates, we often separate variables as follows: $$\psi(r,\theta\,\phi)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi).$$ For simplicity let's take our domain as:
$$0\leq r \leq a, \ \ 0\leq \phi <2\pi, \ \ 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$$
and we'll consider the Laplace equation, but the following discussion applies for other PDEs. Inserting this ansatz into the PDE, we eventually obtain an ODE for the azimuthal equation eigenfunctions:

$$\Phi''=-m^2 \Phi, \ \ 0\leq \phi < 2\pi$$ where $m$ is any constant. Now, the general solution is of the form: $$\Phi_g(\phi)=A\cos(m\phi) + B\sin(m\phi).$$ We impose the condition of continuity at $\phi=0$ (usually a physical argument) to get: $$A=A\cos(2\pi m)+B\sin(2\pi m).$$

Several sources (for example [here](http://www.physics.sfsu.edu/%7Elea/courses/ugrad/360notes8.PDF), [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/blayneh/cylcoord.pdf) and even Griffith's text for quantum mechanics) argue that the azimuthal equation must satisfy $\Phi(k + 2\pi) = \Phi(k)$ for all $k$ to ensure that the solution is single-valued at a given point, and thus $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. However, I am not sure that I am convinced with this argument because our original ODE is defined only in the domain $0\leq \phi < 2\pi$ and the solution $\Phi_g$ inside does not (mathematically) extend outside of this region. The reason I bring this up is that by this logic, the function:

$$\Phi(\phi) = \sin \left(\frac{\phi-2\pi t}{2}\right), \ \ 2\pi t \leq x < 2\pi(t+1), \ \ t = ...,-1,0, 1,2, ...$$

(plotted below) satisfies the $\Phi$ ODE with $m=\frac{1}{2}$ and periodicity $\Phi(k + 2\pi) = \Phi(k)$ is preserved, despite this not being the eigenfunction we seek (the derivative isn't continuous at the boundary).

[image]

I'm not convinced by the above argument, because I don't think we can simply extend the solution from one interval to another, rather we would have to solve the ODE in each interval separately and "patch" them together according to single-valuedness.

I was wondering if a better argument would be to use the continuity of the derivative $\Phi'$ at the boundary $\phi=0$ (this can be shown by integrating the $\Psi$ ODE and using continuity of $\Psi$). The previous approach used this fact implicitly by extending the functions outside of their domain. In this case we would get: $Bm = -Am \sin(2\pi m) + Bm \cos(2 \pi m) $. Solving the resulting equations shows that $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the eigenfunctions are sines and cosines. Either way, we get the same answer. My question is: is my understanding of this situation correct (continuity of function + derivatives are required), or is the other approach also correct?

Comment: *Periodicity* really means $f(\phi+2\pi)=f(\phi)$, not only the continuity at a specific point $\phi=0$. Also, this point is usually chosen arbitrarily - it is just the coordinate system, which can be rotated, without changing the results.

Comment: It's worth noting that your function can be expressed in terms of "standard" eigenfunctions via a Fourier series:$$|\sin(\phi/2)| = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty \frac{2}{(4m^2-1)\pi} e^{i m x}.$$So in some sense your proposed solution is included in the "standard" set of eigenfunctions.

Comment: @RogerVadim By rotation of the coordinate system could I just define $\xi = \phi  + \pi$ and solve: $\frac{d^2\Phi_2}{d\xi^2}=-\mu^2\Phi_2, 0\leq \xi < 2\pi$ in addition to $\frac{d^2\Phi_1}{d\phi^2}=-m^2\Phi_1, 0\leq \phi < 2\pi$ (solve for $\Phi_1, \Phi_2$ on different intervals). Then by invoking single-valuedness: $\Phi_1(0) = \Phi_1(2\pi), \Phi_2(0) = \Phi_2(2\pi), \Phi_1(0) = \Phi_2(\pi), \Phi_1(\pi) = \Phi_2(0)$ we can completely determine the eigenfunctions. (I think this issue is mainly an artefact of the coordinate system, since the boundary is somewhat artificial).

Comment: @Steve you can rotate the coordinate system by an arbitrary angle - usually the system should remain invariant in this case, hence the periodicity for every point. But one could imagine a class of problem without rotational symmetry, where the point $\phi=0$ is indeed special.